# Application is not loaded on web server

Tags: php, .htaccess

I uploaded my application on web server location var/www/html/opencart. Open cart is my application name.But it is not loaded on the server.My url : "209.190.34.146/opencart/upload/" .it displays nothing.No error on browser.What should i do to fix it.

Comment: Check your Apache server's `error.log` file.

Answer (score 0):

What files are in the upload folder?

Assuming your web-server is correctly configured, try creating test page index.html

Answer (score 0):

as you have using windows server there is path problem in `config.php` file

try this if you have sub folder use '/' e.g /opencart/upload/ AND replace [YOUR-SUB-FOLDERS-NAME] with your sub folder or directory names use same in admin `config.php`

```
<?php
// HTTP
define('HTTP_SERVER', 'http://209.190.34.146/YOUR-SUB-FOLDERS-NAME/');

// HTTPS
define('HTTPS_SERVER', 'http://209.190.34.146/YOUR-SUB-FOLDERS-NAME/');

// DIR
define('DIR_APPLICATION', 'C:\wamp\www\209.190.34.146\YOUR-SUB-FOLDERS-NAME/catalog/');
define('DIR_SYSTEM', 'C:\wamp\www\209.190.34.146\YOUR-SUB-FOLDERS-NAME/system/');
define('DIR_DATABASE', 'C:\wamp\www\209.190.34.146\YOUR-SUB-FOLDERS-NAME/system/database/');
define('DIR_LANGUAGE', 'C:\wamp\www\209.190.34.146\YOUR-SUB-FOLDERS-NAME/catalog/language/');
define('DIR_TEMPLATE', 'C:\wamp\www\209.190.34.146\YOUR-SUB-FOLDERS-NAME/catalog/view/theme/');
define('DIR_CONFIG', 'C:\wamp\www\209.190.34.146\YOUR-SUB-FOLDERS-NAME/system/config/');
define('DIR_IMAGE', 'C:\wamp\www\209.190.34.146\YOUR-SUB-FOLDERS-NAME/image/');
define('DIR_CACHE', 'C:\wamp\www\209.190.34.146\YOUR-SUB-FOLDERS-NAME/system/cache/');
define('DIR_DOWNLOAD', 'C:\wamp\209.190.34.146\test.com\YOUR-SUB-FOLDERS-NAME/download/');
define('DIR_LOGS', 'C:\wamp\www\209.190.34.146\YOUR-SUB-FOLDERS-NAME/system/logs/');
```